# Reopen autoclosed PRs - Renovate

Tags: renovate

Renovate autocloses PRs that it created when there are config changes in renovate.json file. Is there any way for renovate to reopen those PRs?

There was a PR 'X' that renovate created, which didn't pass some of the checks. some configs in renovate.json were later changed and due to this, renovate autoclosed 'X' PR.

How can we make renovate reopen/ create new PR 'X' for the same version upgrade? Checking the `If you want to rebase/retry this PR, click this checkbox.` checkbox did not work, the PR 'X' still remained closed, and the branch it created for the PR is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [recreateclosed](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#recreateclosed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add env 'RENOVATE_RECREATE_WHEN' or parameter 'recreateWhen'(allowedValues: auto, always, never) to Renovate config.
You can select which behavior you want from Renovate:

- always: Recreates all closed or blocking PRs
- auto: The default option. Recreates only immortal PRs (default)
- never: No PR is recreated, doesn't matter if it is immortal or not